# Cakephp 3 - Loading security component in appcontroller

Tags: cakephp

I am using the security component to recover blackholed requests and redirect them to https

This is working fine but i'd like to use the same thing for all my admin prefix routed controllers

I was wondering if it's possible/safe to put the code in my appcontroller rather than adding it to each controler as that would cause a lot of code duplication

I can't find much on the internet about doing it this way so i thought i'd ask on here

Has anybody out there done this?

I would really appreciate some guidance

Thanks

Comment: Yes it's OK, but why do you think this would compromise security?

Comment: I don't know to be honest. I was just a bit suspicious of it because the cookbook doesn't do it that way and i couldn't find much about it online! Good to know i can go ahead and do it though so thanks.